# How to print an array without brackets, commas, and apostrophes

Tags: python-3.x

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9H17.png is an image of the code working and the output.

I have a homework assignment to create a high score list from inputted names and scores. It is supposed to display them in order, and I have it working, I just cannot for the life of me figure out how to remove the unnecessary formatting from my code. I've tried doing join stuff, can't really figure out the converting to String options... I will probably get full credit for this solution, but I really want to know how to make it more easily readable.

```
Scores = []
count = 0
question = True

while question == True:
    name = str(input("Whose score are you inputting?"))
    if name != "Done":
        score = int(input("What did " + name + " score?"))
        entry = score, name
        Scores.append(entry)
        count = count + 1
    elif name == "Done" and count < 5:
        print("You haven't input 5 scores yet!")
    else:
        question = False
        Scores.sort(reverse=True)
        print(*Scores, sep='\n')

input("")
```

Comment: Hi, try replacing `entry` with a string in whatever format you want it to be. For instance `entry = "{score}, {name}".format(score=score, name=name)`. The way you are doing it now, `entry` is a tuple and by default printed like that.

Comment: @mortysporty The problem has been found! I've literally spent an hour and a half googling ways to do stuff to arrays to make the formatting better and they all would have so many issues! I had a tuple the entire time! Thanks a ton! ^^

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped!